# Linux user that can read-only all files?

Tags: linux, read-only

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a user with read-only access to all files? (ie root without writing permissions)](https://superuser.com/questions/76701/how-can-i-create-a-user-with-read-only-access-to-all-files-ie-root-without-writ)

Is it possible to create a user in Linux/Unix that can see all files on the system, but in a read-only capacity?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/76701/how-can-i-create-a-user-with-read-only-access-to-all-files-ie-root-without-writ

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the classic unix permissions model. You may be able to do something with SELinux or with raw ACLs, but I don't know anything about those options.